# How to see unremoved event listeners?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

I am building a react project that requires a bunch of event listeners. I am removing the listeners as the components unmount, but I want to double check whether they are properly removed or not.

Are unremoved event listeners stacked together somewhere or are we unable to see them? I have searched the web and all I found were:

1. getEventListener(${target_element});
2. chrome devtools -> elements tab -> Event Listeners
3. chrome devtools -> sources tab -> Event Listener Breakpoints -> fire my event

None of them seems to display the unremoved listeners being stacked. I want to see something like `{ click: Array(5) }` as to show 5 duplicate listeners are dangling.